# I am trying to create a button with jQuery. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I am trying to make a start button, but whenever I test the program, it shows up but doesn't do anything.

This is what I have:

```js
var startGame = function() { //when the start button is clicked, the game starts
  $('#startButton').click(function() {
    $('#main').hide();
    playing = true;
  });
}

$(document).ready(startGame()); //when the html loads, start the function

while (playing) {
  //this is the main loop for the program
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="textHere">
  <div id="main">
    <h1>I am a computer.</h1>
    <a class="button" id="startButton">START</a> 
    <!--this is the button-->
  </div>
  <script src="" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js ""></script>
  </script>
  <script src='I%20am%20a%20computer.js'></script> <!--where it gets the script-->
</body>
```

Comment: because you are not setting `startGame` as the `ready` callback, you are executing it and setting the return value as the callback. You also have a few html syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the `startGame` function instead of passing it to `document.ready`. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(startGame);
```

When you put parentheses after a function name, it calls it immediately. To use the function as a value, leave out the parentheses.